# Что не так с кодом - флаг RE?

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Имеется задача: на вход подаётся файл "input.txt". На первой строке этого файла находится число k, на второй строке дана последовательность чисел, записанных через пробел, числа в дипазоне 0 < n < 99999999. Если в последовательности есть два числа, сумма которых равна k, то в файл "output.txt" записать 1, иначе - 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(NULL);
  unsigned int k, num, ind=0, mxN=2e6;

  unsigned int arr[mxN];

  ifstream in("input.txt");
  ofstream out("output.txt");

  in >> k;

  while (in >> num)
  {
    arr[ind] = num;
    ++ind;
  }

  // 2 pointers
  sort(arr, arr+ind);
  int l = 0;
  int r = ind - 1;
  while (l != r)
  {
    if (arr[l] + arr[r] < k) 
    {
      ++l;
    }
    else if (arr[l] + arr[r] > k)
    {
      --r;
    }
    else {
      out << "1";
      out.close();
      return 0;
    }
  }

  out << "0";
  out.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Написал такое решение. Оно рабочее, но на одном из тестов падает с флагом - RE. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Runtime Exception, программа крашится

Comment: что будет при нулевой длине массива?

Comment: 34:23: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'unsigned int [*]' .. Вы читаете сообщения при сборке и рантайме?

Comment: @Maggot При сборке на моей машине всё впорядке и тесты проходит. При каких входных данных вы получили данную ошибку или она возникает на этапе сборки?

Comment: @IvanPetrov код из вопроса. Вы подумайте просто что происходит на 34 строке

Comment: @Maggot аааа, если массив нулевой длины, то r = -1. Я правильно понял?